# Meaning of 小せェもんに縛られてる

Tags: meaning, verbs, manga, passive-voice, sports

Context: in a flashback, a Cuban boxer is thinking back to when he was in Cuba before seeking asylum (亡命) and migrating to America. He had just won a gold medal for his country in the Olympics.

> 国のためとか…　**小せェもんに縛られてる**から底辺止まりなんだよ　凡人共が

My literal translation attempt is:

> For their country, ordinary people remain in the lower classes because
>   they are bound by little things.

What is the meaning of 小せェもんに縛られてる? I understand the literal meaning, but what is he actually referring to? Is this some kind of metaphor I am not getting?

[image: comic strip]

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This 小せえもん ("trivial things") is a paraphrase of 国のため(とか). It's read like `trivial things such as "for our country"` or `"For our country"... such trivial things`. In other words, this guy is making light of petty nationalism, and seeing something even bigger than Cuba.

EDIT: In case you missed it, this が after 凡人共 is a derogatory vocative-like particle, e.g., "この馬鹿者が!" = "You idiot!" It's also working as the implied subject of 縛られてる and 底辺止まり, though.